# Windows 8 won't burn DVD anymore but reads DVD

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd

The title says everything.

My laptop does not recognize empty DVD anymore, but has no problem with DVD with movies or data on it.

I am using Windows 8.1 on a Sony Vaio svf1521r6ew

Comment: One possibility: bad media.  I have had numerous cheap blank DVDs fail in the same way.  Buy one good quality blank DVD and see if the drive recognizes it.

Comment: The first thing is to confirm whether this is a h/w or s/w issue. Can u get access to an external dvd Drive? Kindly plug it and try burning a dvd. If successful your laptop dvd drive is malfuctioned

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not recognize"? Does it simply refuse to burn to it, or does it say the drive is empty? Are there any error messages? What program are you using to burn the dvd, or are you just using Window's built in burning abilities?

Comment: @RobinHood it says that I have to insert a DVD in the drive. I use the Windows program

Comment: I would suggest installing a different dvd suite (eg: Ashampoo Burning Studio 6 free), don't actually burn anything to the disc, just use it see if it too complains about inserting a dvd. This will help determine if it's a disc issue, or software issue.